# How to create an open field poll on blogger

Tags: forms, blogspot

I need to create a poll/form with a few questions. The issue is that the possible answers are too varied to be able to predict them and put them as options (eg: "favourite fruit"), so I need it to be an open field option (as in the user can fill in his own answer). Then I need that input to be published on my blogger page/post.

eg:

Favourite color:
Blue

Favourite fruit:
Apple

Is there anyway to do that? I dont know which way to start looking, if in the direction of polls, questionnaires or forms.

Any piece of advice would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Blogger doesn't provide any option to directly allow users to publish answers from polls into blog post.
You may use free online form generator websites ( Google Docs Forms , emailmeform and other form generating tools) to get the poll result in your email.
And manually add the data to your blog post.